# Get flatten 2d array from a multidimensional array with parent-child relationships and inconsistent scalar data

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, flatten

I have a multidimensional array with parent-child relationships and I want to flatten its data into a 2d array of the scalar data from each level using recursion.

```
[
    'children' => [
        [
            'id' => 123,
            'title' => 'test',
            'children' => [
                [
                    'id' => 345,
                    'title' => 'test 1',
                    'children' => [],
                ],
                [
                    'id' => 567,
                    'title' => 'test 2',
                    'children' => [
                        [
                            'id' => 789,
                            'title' => 'test 3',
                            'children' => [],
                        ],
                        [
                            'id' => 333,
                            'title' => 'tset 4',
                            'children' => [
                                [
                                    'id' => 222,
                                    'title' => 'test 5',
                                    'children' => [],
                                ],
                                [
                                    'id' => 111,
                                    'title' => 'test 55',
                                    'children' => [],
                                ],
                                [
                                    'id' => 444,
                                    'title' => 'test 556',
                                    'children' => [],
                                ],
                                [
                                    'id' => 666,
                                    'title' => 'test44',
                                    'children' => [],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        [
                            'id' => '5556',
                            'identifier' => 'test 2',
                            'children' => [
                                [
                                    'id' => 888,
                                    'title' => 'test 2',
                                    'children' => [],
                                ],
                                [
                                    'id' => 255,
                                    'title' => 'tset',
                                    'children' => [],
                                ],
                                [
                                    'id' => 454,
                                    'title' => 'warm-up-5837',
                                    'children' => [],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

My current code:

```
function flattenTree(array $elements, $i, $branch)
{
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        $branch[$i++] = [
            'id' => $element['id'],
            'title' => $element['title']
        ];
        if (!empty($element['children'])) {
               flattenTree($element['children'], $i, $branch);
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [
        [id] => 123
        [title] => 'test'
    ]
    [1] => [
        [id] => 345
        [title] => 'test 1'
    ]
    [2] => [
        [id] => 567
        [title] => 'test 2'
    ]
    [3] => [
        [id] => 789
        [title] => 'test 3' 
    ]
    [4] => [
        [id] => 333
        [title] => 'tset 4'
    ]
    [5] => [
        [id] => 222
        [title] => 'test 5'
    ]
    [6] => [
        [id] => 111
        [title] => 'test 55'
    ]
    [7] => [
        [id] => 444
        [title] => 'test 556'
    ]
    [8] => [
        [id] => 666
        [title] => 'test44'
    ]
    [9] => [
        [id] => '5556'
        [identifier] => 'test 2'
    ]
    [10] => [
        [id] => 888
        [title] => 'test 2'
    ]   
    [11] => [
        [id] => 255
        [title] => 'tset'
    ]
)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you showed the data as from a `var_export($theArray)` so we could copy/paste the data easily to test an answer

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of `$this->flattenTree($element['children'], $i, $branch)`…

Comment: You are also using `$this` but you have not shown the method as a method, but just as a function? Do we assume it is really in a class or that `$this` is an error

Comment: @RiggsFolly removed $this

Comment: And the `exit;` statement will of course also prevent this from passing the gathered data back up to the next level caller.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What's the expected output for this?

Comment: It doesn't seem like `$i` serves any purpose here, remove it. Then all you need is `$branch = flattenTree($element['children'], $branch)`.

Comment: @BhumiShah Can you share an online link for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of observations.

- You are using `$i`. This pointer needs to be passed by reference in every subsequent method call, else the previous `$i` location will be overridden when the recursive call comes back.
- You are adding results to `$branch`. Now, you would again wish to pass this as a reference to affect the same output variable.
- `return $branch;` This is entirely not needed if you passing the output variable pass by reference.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function flattenTree(array $elements, &$i, &$branch){
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        if(isset($element['id'], $element['title'])){ // you can remove this if condition if you find it redundant and if your array is symmetric
            $branch[$i++] = [
                'id' => $element['id'],
                'title' => $element['title']
            ];
        }
        
        if (!empty($element['children'] ?? [])) {
            flattenTree($element['children'], $i, $branch);
        }
    }
}


$output = [];

$i = 0;

flattenTree($your_array, $i, $output);

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your coding attempt looks more complicated than necessary.

1. Iterate the `children` element of whatever array is passed into the recursive function.
2. Unconditionally cache the `id` and `title`/`identifier` data.
3. If the current child/row has a populated `children` element, then make the recursive call and push its returned payload as individual elements into the parent's cache.
4. Each level will pass its payload up. On the top level, the whole flattened result will be returned.

There is no need to maintain a counter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/trQdI))

```
function flattenTree(array $tree): array
{
    $flat = [];
    foreach ($tree['children'] ?? [] as $child) {
        $flat[] = ['id' => $child['id'], 'title' => $child['title'] ?? $child['identifier']];
        if (!empty($child['children'])) {
           array_push($flat, ...flattenTree($child, $flat));
        }
    }
    return $flat;
}
var_export(flattenTree($array));
```

---

If you want to keep that `identifier` key in the output, then you can merely filter the `$child` data with `is_scalar()` before caching. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gqLEb))

```
function flattenTree(array $tree): array
{
    $flat = [];
    foreach ($tree['children'] ?? [] as $child) {
        $flat[] = array_filter($child, 'is_scalar');        #<--- HERE
        if (!empty($child['children'])) {
           array_push($flat, ...flattenTree($child, $flat));
        }
    }
    return $flat;
}
var_export(flattenTree($array));
```